# cloudinary-direct upload from browser not uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

When I try to upload a file directly to Cloudinary nothing happens. The file name in the selected file field is deleted and no file is added to my Cloudinary accounts' Media Library.

This is my index.html.erb file

```
<%= cloudinary_js_config %>
<%= form_tag(cardset_cards_path(@cardset, @card), :method => :post) do  %>
  <%= cl_image_upload_tag(:image_id) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

My application.js file

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require cloudinary
```

I do have the downloaded cloudinary.yml file with api_key and api_secret...
I'm using Rails 4, I haven't set my config.assets.enabled = false, so I belive I am using Asset Pipeline by default.

I believe I'm following the example in Cloudinary, but my Cloudinary Account Media Library doesn't show any file uploaded. I've tried adding :html => {:multipart => true}, but the same things happens nothing. I've tried different things in the controller to get the returned id, but since nothing is happening, I think I'd just be happy to get a file into my Cloudinary Media Library.

-hoping to rise from the dirt to the Clouds

Comment: Please try to run the page on chrome and look at the network tab of the developer tools. You should be able to see if a request is executed and its result.

Comment: Hi Tal, Thanks for the reply. No requests show up when I choose the file. When I hit the submit button, a post is sent to my cards controller with action create. Then I have a request to cloudinary.js?body=1 which says 304 not modified. From the Cloudinary docs, the upload to Cloudinary should happen before the controller action is sent. So I guess nothing is being sent to Cloudinary.

Comment: Please make sure that cloudinary.js contains the correct scripts. 1) See if $.cloudinary is defined in the developer tools console. 2) See that $.cloudinary is present in the cloudinary.js file. (maybe you created a file called cloudinary.js in your local project and it's confusing the asset pipeline).

Comment: VICTORY! I had my own cloudinary.js in vendor/assets/javascripts/. So my Chrome->Tools->DeveloperTools->Console had an error: Uncaught Type Error: Can not call method config of undefined.Thanks Tal Lev-Ami!